# How to find the specified root of a number?

Tags: python

**For example, I want to find the fifth root of 4, but I don't know how to do it.
Can anyone guide me?

I want to write a function with two inputs, the first input is the specified number and the second input specifies the root number.
For example, the fifth root of 4**

Comment: You mean like `4**(1/5)`, which is `1.3195079107728942`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def root_func(number,root):
    return number ** (1/root)

print(root_func(9,2)) 
##Output:3
```